# chrome binary installed by webdrivermanager is not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I see in logs that `webdrivermanager` successfully downloads the chrome binary inside `.m2`. However, it is still getting picked from some other location.

The same implementation works locally but not in Azure Pipeline.

```
---------------- 
TEST STARTED: Verify login

[INFO] Running Verify login
[main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Reading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ to seek chromedriver 
[main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader - Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/92.0.4515.107/chromedriver_win32.zip 
[main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader - Extracting binary from compressed file chromedriver_win32.zip 
[main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as C:\Users\vstsagent\.m2\repository\webdriver\chromedriver\win32\92.0.4515.107\chromedriver.exe 

Sep 02, 2021 2:38:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome 
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()` 
[main] INFO net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.ProvideNewDriver - Instantiating driver 
[main] INFO net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.ProvideNewDriver - Driver capabilities: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, chrome.switches: --incognito, --disable-geol..., goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--incognito, --disable-geolocation, --enable-automation, --test-type], extensions: []}, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging..., platform: ANY, version: } 

Starting ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.101 (af52a90bf87030dd1523486a1cd3ae25c5d76c9b-refs/branch-heads/4472@{#1462}) on port 23809 
Only local connections are allowed. 
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. 
ChromeDriver was started successfully. 
[main] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - 
---------------- 
- TEST FAILED - 
---------------- 

TEST FAILED WITH ERROR: Verify error icon on missing mandatory fields 

--------------------------- 

[main] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - TEST FAILED AT STEP Given Sample Web page 

[main] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

First para in the logs, you'll see that chrome 93 is installed in `.m2` folder and last para first line it is still picking chrome 91. I am not getting how. I have already all chrome instances.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to keep a version of chromedriver already?

Like this:

```
// version is your stable version
     WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version(version).setup();
```

Comment: No I am। using `WebDriver.chromedriver().setUp()`